# How can I use a string as a method name in C#?

Tags: c#

I made a short method to make it easier to change the console color.

```
string c = red;
if (c == "red")
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

I have this for every color. Can I just type the color into the method and use the string as the color name? Like:

```
string c = Red;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.c;
```

So that I don't need to specify every color. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: "Red" is not a method name.  If you are not using IntelliSense then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think you want Enum.Parse?

Comment: Red is member of ConsoleColor enumeration. you can use Enum.Parse to convert string into that enum and set that to ForegroundColor property.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which will take a string and try to convert it to an enum value (in your case you're working with the `ConsoleColor` enum). If the parsing is successful, the method returns `true` and the `out` parameter will contain the converted value; otherwise it returns `false`.

Here's an example of a method that takes a string and changes the console color if the conversion is successful:

```
static bool TryChangeConsoleForeColor(string newColor)
{
    ConsoleColor foreColor;

    if (Enum.TryParse(newColor, true, out foreColor))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main()
{
    string color = "Red";

    Console.WriteLine($"Changing color to '{color}'...");
    TryChangeConsoleForeColor(color); // Ignores return value

    color = "Car";

    Console.WriteLine($"Changing color to '{color}'...");
    if (!TryChangeConsoleForeColor(color))
    {
        // Do something if TryChange fails
        Console.WriteLine($"Cannot change color to '{color}'");
    }

    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this could works for you purpose:

```
    string color = "Red";
    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), color);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not answer your question directly but perhaps it may steer you in the right direction.

You could create a color service that has property names of the colors if you really wanted to go that far.

These articles may help if you go the enum route.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx